# Adding words into string array from file C++

Tags: c++

Basically what I'm doing is reading words from a file, taking only the letters out of it, putting them into an array and counting how many I have. The problem is that the way I've written it, when there are two non-letters next to each other another word is created. What should I change here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str[10000];
    string temp = "";
    char c;
    int i = 0, count = 0;

    //Open file
    fstream sample;
    sample.open("sample.txt");

    while (!sample.eof()){
            sample.get(c);

            //convert character to lowercase and append to temp. string
            if ((c>=65 && c<=90) || (c>=97 && c<=122)){
                    c = tolower(c);
                    temp += c;
            }
 //when a word ends, add it to array and add 1 to the word count
            else if (c<65 || (c>90 && c<97) || c>122){
                    str[i] = temp;
                    count++;
                    i++;
                    temp = "";
            }
    }
    sample.close();

    cout << "The number of words found in the file was " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well you've written it so "when a word ends, add it to array and add 1 to the word count", but you count every non-alpha character as a word end. So maybe when a word ends, you should look for the next word start before starting and ending a new word, no?

Comment: while (!file.eof) doesnt do what you think. You want while(file)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure how to implement it. How can I say "start the next word when the previous character was not a letter"?

Comment: Where did you learn to use the ASCII codes rather than character literals?  For example, instead of `65` you could use `'A'`.  I'm curious because I see a lot of these examples.

Comment: You `while` expression should be `while (sample.get(c))`.  Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ eof bad" for the reason.

Comment: pm: This is my first C++ program, coming from C, so thank you for letting me know early on. Thomas: seemed like the easiest way to me, that's all. Also, I did see that thread, but I wasn't sure if I should use sample.get or eof. I'll take another look at it.

Comment: I'm using an array of string-types so that I can easily implement a function to search for a word later.

Comment: Even in C, I use `'A'` instead of 65.  In the embedded systems world, we would use `0x41` but to each his own.  I just find numeric ASCII values harder to read than their character literals.

Comment: Update: I thought some more on Dronz' suggestion and fixed my problem. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you can, please avoid using raw arrays in C++ outside of classes which can control the lifetime of the array via destructors etc. It is considered good practice to do this. Instead use the container classes provided by the standard library (like vector, array, ...).

Second you can use stringstream's to get words out of the file more easily.

Third please refrain from *using namespace std;*. This is also considered
bad practice.

Slightly better example for your problem of getting the strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> str;

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream sample("sample.txt");

    std::stringstream strm;
    strm << sample.rdbuf();
    while(strm) {
        std::string word;
        strm >> word;
        if (word.empty()) continue;
        str.push_back(word);
    }

    std::cout << "Word count: " << str.size() << std::endl;
}
```

I hope you can adapt the rest of your problem easily.